# Where in the world is decompilation and reverse engineering for security research legal?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, software, security

Disclaimer: IANAL, the following is just my research up to now.

I understand that in many jurisdictions, reverse engineering - and especially decompilation of software without explicit permission from the vendor are a gray zone or outright forbidden. The usual understanding seems to be that reverse engineering or decompilation constitutes creating a copy of the software, and therefore infringes on copyright.

However, there are usually some exceptions, for example:

- In EU law, the exception is usually to ascertain interoperability of the software (with some caveats) (see [Directive 2009/24/EC — the legal protection of computer programs](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=LEGISSUM%3Ami0016))
- Under US law, there is the fair use doctrine (cf. [Sega vs. Accolade (977 F.2d 1510)](https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/summaries/segaenters-accolade-9thcir1992.pdf))

On the other hand, the Australian [Copyright Amendment (Computer Programs) Bill 1999](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2004B00467/Explanatory%20Memorandum/Text) specifically mentions "security testing and correcting a security flaw" as an exception where copyright is not infringed.

Under which (other) jurisdictions is reverse engineering and decompilation for security purposes explicitly legal?